# C++ потоки. Потеря данных

Tags: c++, многопоточность, dll

Есть dll с одной вызываемой функцией F()
В ней происходит, с помощью curl, POST-запрос(без обработки ответа) на некий ресурс
Проблема в следующем:
Я в приложении(игре) вызываю функцию из этого dll передав в неё некие данные.
Но во время запроса процесс повисает в ожидании ответа, что, вроде как логично.
Я попытался обернуть curl в поток, но теперь, данные передаваемые curl теряются, либо приходит мусор.
Есть подозрение, что функция F при завершении как-то убивает все данные, которые в неё были переданы; соответственно, в потоке(т.к. ссылка у данных на одну область(как я предполагаю)), они теряются. Это моё предположение.
Подскажите в чём реально может быть проблема и как её можно решить?
P.S. На сайте curl нашел инфу CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, думал может это поможет, но нет

```
void curl_POST(const char* url, const char* data, char* output, int outputSize){

    CURL* curl = nullptr;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {

        const char* local_buffer = data;
        std::string prt = std::regex_replace(url, std::regex("\""), "\0");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, prt);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(data));
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, local_buffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}

int __stdcall F(char* output, int outputSize, const char* req, const char** args, int argsCnt)
{
    std::thread ([](char* output, int outputSize, const char* req, const char** args, int argsCnt)
        {
            curl_POST(args[0], args[1], output, outputSize);
        },  output,  outputSize, req,  args,  argsCnt).detach();
}
```

Comment: Все правильно, необходимо следить, чтобы данные, с которыми работает поток, не протухали, пока тот не завершится. Это также подразумевает, что нельзя вызывать detach() у потока.

Comment: @user7860670 если не использовать detach, то остаётся join, но, если использовать Join, то это по сути будет то же самое(в моём случае), что если бы я делал и без потоков. Так что же мне всё-таки нужно сделать, чтобы не терять передаваемые в поток данные?

Comment: Я же уже написал, надо следить, чтобы объекты, передаваемые в поток, оставались живыми пока поток не завершится, то бишь пока не вызван `join`.

Comment: @user7860670 ну я же написал, что если я буду использовать join, то зависание на время исполнения запроса никуда не исчезнет, а мне этого не нужно. Для этого я и собирался использовать потоки

Comment: Такое будет происходить, только если вызвать `join` сразу после создания потока, как сейчас `detach`. А вам нужно вызывать его намного позже, когда поток выполнил работу, или программа завершается или когда он в будущем станет не нужным.

Comment: @user7860670 Ок, давайте еще раз
Смотрите. При вызове этой функции в dll, я ожидаю, что произойдет запрос к некому ресурсу. При этом мне не важно как долго он будет происходить, мне важно одно, чтобы он выполнялся так, чтобы не останавливать работу программы. Т.е., как я понимаю в другом потоке.
Теперь возвращаемся к функции в dll. Запрос длится от 2х до 5 секунд. Я ожидаю, что я вызову эту функцию и запрос выполнится без остановки программы.

Comment: @user7860670 Если я напишу, как вы говорите(хотя я так тоже пробовал иначе бы не стал тут задавать вопрос):
`F(){
std::thread th()
{
curl()
};
th.join()
}`
Это не отличается от того, как если бы я не использовал потоки. Вы говорите нужно вызвать тогда, когда поток завершиться. А как мне об этом узнать? Любые ожидания в этой функции недопустимы, т.к. она же застопорит выполнение программы. Отмечу, что я могу менять что-то только в этой dll. В коде основной программы я ничего менять не могу.

Comment: Владение потоком естественно должно передаваться взывающей стороне, и join естественно должен вызываться не в этой функции, а когда-то потом. Если в приложении именно такой dll интерфейс и менять его нельзя, то вам наверное имеет смысл вместо потока создать там новый процесс, передав требуемые данные через файл на диске или через stdin. Тогда не надо будет заботится о времени жизни объектов и потока.

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо за наводку на создание процесса. Действительно выглядит так, что могло бы мне помочь. Но у меня пока нет возможности и времени проверить. Поэтому, если позволите украсть у вас еще немного времени на пару вопросов.

Comment: @user7860670 Как я успел посмотреть, во всех примерах, которые мне удалось найти, отдельным процессом запускается .exe файл. (http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/Process_thread/create_child_process.htm)
Т.е. мне обязательно надо из моей функцию curl() собрать exe и везде его таскать вместе с dll? Но это же неудобно
Есть ли какой-то способ запустить в отдельном потоке функцию или может просто другой .cpp файл(но тогда в этом случае не придется ли его с dll таскать вместе)?

Comment: На Windows 10 curl есть из коробки. Но вообще, да неудобно. Раз интерфейс dll кривой, то придется вам страдать.